# Android market initiate remote download

Tags: android, google-play

I would like to know how the android market initiates the remote download through their website. I'm guessing there is some sort of push notification system. I want to know if it's possible to do the same thing using a different web interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only possibility I see is to use the [C2D (Cloud to Device) messaging API](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/index.html) provided by Google. In that way you could send an install intent to the device. However that would always open the market locally on the device from which the user can then install the app.

Obviously Google can bypass these "limitations" :)

Comment: The C2DM website says that you can silently sync data in the background when a message is received.  Quote: "For example, the application might post a notification, display a custom user interface, or silently sync data."

Comment: @Austyn sure...just the installation of an app must go over the native android market app as far as I know.

Comment: I didn't know if he just wasn't sure how to send a C2DM message like they do, or force the install of an app from a non-google website, so I gave a general answer.  I agree that they probably won't let other developers send a message that forces an app install.

Comment: @juri yes I want to initiate the app download on the phone from a website, and let the user take it on from there. But cloud computing is only available on 2.2 upwards but I've seen it happen on 1.6 (my old g1). so in such a case how do they do it?

Comment: @hades probably the same way as they are able to remotely remove malicious apps from devices without any confirmation (http://goo.gl/BWW3). There must be some service that connects to Google allowing them to do such stuff. In your case, if you want to be backward compatible to older versions, you most probably have to differentiate. Basically implement your own small "push" service for older android versions and use the C2DM for newer ones in order to leverage Google's infrastructure. Alternatively, on your install button on the website could just redirect to Google's new market :)

Answer (score 2):

They use [Android Cloud to Device Messaging](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/index.html) (C2DM).  They allow anyone with a server of their own to implement this service.

From the site:

> Android Cloud to Device Messaging (C2DM) is a service that helps developers send data from servers to their applications on Android devices. The service provides a simple, lightweight mechanism that servers can use to tell mobile applications to contact the server directly, to fetch updated application or user data. The C2DM service handles all aspects of queueing of messages and delivery to the target application running on the target device.